# Removing Pandas DF stored as a List

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do a webscraping but my pandas DF appears to be a list, so i cant export it to excel.

How can I remove the df from inside this list?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

link = 'https://www.reit.com/data-research/reit-market-data/us-reit-industry-equity-market-cap'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(link)

df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)

print(df)
```

it returns me

```
[    End of  Year  All REITs  # of  REITs  Market  Capitalization  Equity  # of  REITs  Market  Capitalization.1  Mortgage  # of  REITs  Market  Capitalization.2 Hybrid  # of  REITs Market  Capitalization.3
0           1971                      34                  1494.3                   12                     332.0                     12                     570.8                  10                    591.6
1           1972                      46                  1880.9                   17                     377.3                     18                     774.7                  11                    728.9
2           1973                      53                  1393.5                   20                     336.0                     22                     517.3                  11                    540.2
3           1974                      53                   712.4                   19                     241.9                     22                     238.8                  12                    231.7
4           1975                      46                   899.7                   12                     275.7                     22                     312.0                  12                    312.0
5           1976                      62                  1308.0                   27                     409.6                     22                     415.6                  13                    482.8
6           1977                      69                  1528.1                   32                     538.1                     19                     398.3                  18                    591.6
7           1978                      71                  1412.4                   33                         30          2001                     182                154898.6                  151                  147092.1                     22                    3990.5                   9                   3816.0
42          2013                     202                670334.1                  161                  608276.6                     41                   62057.4                  --                       --
43          2014                     216                907425.5                  177                  846410.3                     39                   61017.2                  --                       --
44          2015                     233                938852.0                  182                  886487.5                     41                   52364.6                  --                       --
45          2016                     224               1018729.9                  184                  960192.8                     40                   58537.1                  --                       --
46          2017                     222               1133697.6                  181                 1065947.7                     41                   67749.9                  --                       --
47          2018                     226               1047641.3                  186                  980314.9                     40                   67326.4                  --                       --
48          2019                     219               1328806.2                  179                 1245878.3                     40                   82927.8                  --                       --
49          2020                     223               1249186.3                  182                 1184150.2                     41                   65036.1                  --                       --]


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 31, in <module>
    df.to_excel(...., index=False)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_excel'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.read_html` always returns a list of dataframe(s) since there may be multiple `<table>` elements in a webpage. Since you need the element inside that possibly 1-element list, you can either do

```
# note the comma!
df, = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
```

or perhaps more readable:

```
df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[0]
```

and then you can proceed as usual, e.g., `df.to_excel(...)`.